# Converting long Strings to Short string codes in R

Tags: r, string, numeric

I have 100+ different long strings and want to code them in short strings. One option is to convert to numeric and then numeric to string codes. Is there any direct way to covert long strings into short string codes? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to add an example of your data and desired result. Are you only trying to capture a unique identifier for each character element (by the way they call them "character elements/vectors" in R instead of "string", but we know what you mean)? Do you want only 1 short character element per long character element, or do you want all of the information from each long character element converted into multiple short character elements? If it's the latter then you can use `strsplit`. If it's the former then you can use hashing or numeric indexing.

Comment: Example: Veector "% respondents very or fairly satisfied with their neighbourhood as a place to live" to be coded as "SS1".

Comment: `factor(z,labels=paste0("SS",seq(length(unique(z)))))` ?

Comment: Example: Character element "% respondents very or fairly satisfied with their neighborhood as a place to live" to be coded as "SS1". So similar to this, I have 100+ Character elements (in a vector) and want to allot short character names (eg SS1 above). So their is no direct way to get it done?